# Yeoman Generator Prompts

Tags: javascript, arrays, yeoman-generator

I am building a yeoman generator, and need to assign an additional value/answer when a prompt is answered.

I have found a way to prompt user with another question, but what I need is to assign a predefined answer automatically in the background - so user wont see it happening, not ask the user another question. Here's an example below. Also need to do this for a list of 12+ values so the 'when' command below isn't ideal as I would have to have the when statement 12+ times

```
   this.prompt([{
      type: 'list',
      name: 'redWhite',
      message: 'what colour',
      choices: ['red', 'white', 'blue', 'black', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'brown']
    }, {
      when: 'redWhite.red',
      type: 'confirm',
      name: 'blue',
      message: 'Red is nice, but how about blue instead?'
    }, 

  /*So instead of prompting user again, just need to assign a predefined value here
   , {
      when: 'redWhite.red',
      answer: redFooBar
    }, */

    {
      when: 'redWhite.white',
      type: 'confirm',
      name: 'green',
      message: 'White is nice, but how about green instead?'
    }, {
      name: 'otherColors',
      message: 'What other colors do you like?'
    }], function (answer) {
      // answer = {
      //   redWhite: 'red',
      //   blue: false,
      //   green: false,
      //   otherColors: 'pink, purple-ish'
      // };
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You dont need the when function here, as it just prompts the user to answer another question.

You can simply use **arrays** in the prompts callback function to get multiple values for one prompted answer, like so

```
//prompt user to answer questions
this.prompt([{
        type: 'list',
        name: "fruit",
        message: "What is your favourite fruit",
        choices: [{
            name: 'Apple',
            value: ['apple', 'Apple Juice', 'Apple Pie' ]
        }, {
            name: 'Banana',
            value: ['banana','Banana Juice','Banana Bread']
        }, {
            name: 'Oranges',
            value: ['oranges','Orange Juice','Orange Pudding']
        }]
    }]);

//confirming the prompts and storing answers - pull required value from array number
this.prompt(prompts, function(answers) {
  this.fruitChoice = answers.fruit[0];
  this.fruitDrink = answers.fruit[1];
  this.fruitDessert = answers.fruit[2];
}
```

Comment: Unrelated question : Can you pass array into templates? and iterate in template? thanks